# Symfony elastic search Query Bool sort

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I'm using `Elastica_Query_Bool()` and have one problem, there is not method to sort (order) results. Does exist any solution to sort result using `Elastica_Query_Bool()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to sort you query :

```
use Elastica\Query;
...
$bool = new Query\Bool();
bool->addMust(..);
$q = new Query($bool);
//$sort = array("entity_id" => array("order" => "asc")); //EXAMPLE 1
$sort = array('_score' => array('order' => 'desc')),     //EXAMPLE 2
$q->setSort(array($sort))
    ->setMinScore(1);
```

[Get more info about the syntax here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_sort_mode_example_usage)